# How to exploit orthogonalization procedure in forward stepwise linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear, stepwise-regression

**Forward Stepwise linear regression** allows to build up a subset of features starting from the intercept. At each step the predictor that most improves the fit is added to the subset.

In the book, it is said

> With many candidate predictors, this might seem like a lot of computation; however, **clever updating algorithms can exploit the QR decomposition** for the current fit to rapidly establish the next candidate.

However it is unclear how to use it QR decomposition.

The reader is given this hint

> Forward stepwise regression. Suppose we have the $QR$ decomposition for the $N\times q$ matrix $X_1$ in a multiple regression problem with response $y$, and we have an additional $p−q$ predictors in the matrix $X_2$. Denote the current residual by $r$. We wish to establish which one of these additional variables will reduce the residual-sum-of squares the most when included with those in $X_1$. Describe an efficient procedure for doing this.

How can I do that?